# jQuery change only certain index of a checkbox name array

Tags: jquery, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox array and a checkall/uncheck all function. When I uncheck all, I want to make sure the first remains checked but it does not work the way below:

```
$("input[name='temps[]']").removeAttr("checked");   // works
$("input[name='temps[0]']").prop("checked", true);  // doesn't work
```

Is there a workaround so that I don't have to hassle with it inside the loop generating checkboxes or I can't do it without e.g. giving the first checkbox an id?

```
$("#firstBox").prop("checked", true)
```

Comment: Maybe using the **first-child** selector?

Comment: Can you post your complete code for better understanding?

Comment: Use this `$('input[name="temp[]"]:first').prop('checked',true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.eq(index )`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`:eq(index )`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get the element at specified index, then the desired operation can be performed

```
$("input[name='temps[]']").eq(index).prop("checked", true);
```

OR,

```
$("input[name='temps[]']:eq(" + index + ")").prop("checked", true);
```

You can also use [`:first` selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to get the first matched DOM element

```
$("input[name='temps[]:first']").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: This .eq() is the solution, perfect. I upvoted all answers but it won't show.

Comment: Oh I see! I'm gonna make that up for.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your HTML source. Element name is `temps[]` and not `temps[0]`. That's why second selector does not work.

To select first, use `.eq(0)`:

```
$("input[name='temps[]']")
    .removeAttr("checked")
    .eq(0)
    .addClass('checked')
    .prop('checked', true)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eq()` function to extract an item by number from a jQuery list. This will create a derived list with just that one item, and then you can proceed as usual:

```
$("input[name='temps[]']").eq(0).prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='temps[]']")[0].prop("checked", true);
```

Or

```
$("input[name='temps[]:first']").prop("checked", true);
```